# MVC Identity - Separation of Concerns

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I am battling with a problem that I am sure is very simple but for some reason my tired (and old) brain cannot work out.

I am creating an application that connects to an existing SQL database that contains users.  I want to do this right.  I have the solution structured with an entity framework data layer, a common poco class layer, a service layer and a MVC UI layer.

I want to use ASP.Net.Identity but with my existing DB users.  I therefore need remove the default requirement of the aspnet_users table, remove the reference to entity framework within my this same UI layer and have the service layer handle the conversion between my db user and the IdentityUser.

I am using VS2019, .Net 4.7 and Identity 2.0.

For further complication I need my common objects layer to be .Net Standard a I plan to many other UI layers such as Xamarin etc...

Can anyone help?

Comment: The big take away here is just writing your own custom *Identity Stores* (data access layer).